# I'd/I'll advise you to

Tags: idiomatic-language

*The police will be here any minute now, so **I'll** advise you to let her go.*

When I search Google I can see that **I'd** is much more used than **I'll** before **advise**, but will it sound unnatural to native speakers to use ***"I'll advise..."***

I'm asking because in my example I feel that using **I'd** would sound to polite in the context?

Answer (score 2):

Neither is particularly unnatural, but "I'd advise you" certainly is way more common. Both are grammatically correct.

"I'd advise you" would not be any less threatening here than "I'll advise you." Whether or not it felt threatening would depend entirely on the tone of voice and context (the context here certainly is threatening, and in a movie the tone would be too).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to a native speaker *I'll advise* sounds unusual, maybe even stilted or unnatural.

**I'll *(I will)* advise you** sounds like a statement about the future.  But it's not clear why the speaker would be making a statement about the future in this context.

**I'd *(I would)* advise you** is a hypothetical, with an unspoken condition like "If you asked me for advice" or "If you want to survive".

Both forms are sometimes used to "soften" a statement, to make it more gentle than simply saying **I advise you to...**, but *would* is more common in this context.  Whether it sounds "too polite" is a matter of opinion and context, but **I'd** is certainly common and idiomatic and sounds fine to this US English speaker.